# Overriding default traefik frontend rule when used with docker compose

Tags: traefik

By default, Traefik creates a frontend rule for newly started docker containers:

https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/

> traefik.frontend.rule=EXPR | Overrides the default frontend rule. Default: Host:{containerName}.{domain} or Host:{service}.{project_name}.{domain} if you are using docker-compose.

I am using docker-compose, and this default behavior is not useful to me. I want to use a docker label and change the frontend rule to be `Host:{hostname}.{domain}` or even the default non-compose `{containerName}.{domain}`, but this does not work. The label does not get parsed. The rule ends up being the literal label string.

I do not understand the documentation.What exactly is the EXPR in `traefik.frontend.rule=EXPR`?

Answer (score 1):

The `{hostname}` and `{domain}` is just to show that the default will take the values from docker. It, unfortunately, doesn't do replacement from global values like it would seem with how that is written.

The `EXPR` would be any sort of traefik rule expression like `"Host: myapp.example.com"`. More examples can be seen in the documentation here: https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#examples